# Change style of table with Eureka Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I use Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 and the Eureka framework.

Is it possible to change the look of the table generated by Eureka?

Put a background image ...

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3):

In fact, Eureka is not a table but will just generate.
So just basically and simply access to the table in order and to implement the actions that you want.

```
let tempImageView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named: "IMG_0213.PNG"))
tempImageView.frame = (self.tableView?.frame)!
self.tableView?.backgroundView = tempImageView
```